# Returning object of type specified in method arguments instead of AnyRef

Tags: spring, scala, generics, reflection

I have the following method:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
class EntityCacheManager {
  def get(cacheId: String, entityClass: Class[_]): AnyRef = { ... }
  //...
}
```

So to use it, i have to write this:

```
val cachedEntity = entityCacheManager.get(cacheId, classOf[SomeEntity]).asInstanceOf[SomeEntity]
```

Is there some way to make `EntityCacheManager.get()` returning instance of type `entityClass` which is specified in method params? I'd like to avoid casting `asInstanceOf` every time i use this method. I know it would be nice to use generic definition of type `EntityCacheManager`, but it's also a spring-managed bean, so i think using generics will cause troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more idiomatic scala approach by using the ClassTag typeclass

```
class EntityCacheManager {
  def get[T: ClassTag](cacheId: String): T = {
    val entityClass = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
    val myObject: T = ??? // you retrieve your object somehow using entityClass
    myObject
  }
}
```

you can now use it like this:

```
val myEntityClassInstance = get[MyEntityClass]("key")
```